# Не могу разобраться с авторизацией в silex

Tags: symfony, php, silex, auth

Решил попробовать silex, использую пример [Silex-MVC-Example-with-Auth](https://github.com/manelpm10/Silex-MVC-Example-with-Auth)

Из коробки все работает, свои страницы добавляются, авторизация проходит. Однако в примере забито, что все урлы требуют авторизации, а /user/login отрывается без нее. Попробовал сделать наоборот, что, например about требует авторизации, а остальные нет. Для этого прописал в security.firewall что:

```
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/.*$',
            'anonymous' => true,
        ),
        'site' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/about$',
            'form'  => array(
                'login_path'         => '/user/login',
                'username_parameter' => 'form[username]',
                'password_parameter' => 'form[password]',
            ),
            'anonymous' => false,
            'logout'    => array('logout_path' => '/user/logout'),
            'users' => $app->share( function () use ( $app )
            {
                return new Model\UserProvider( $app['db'] );
            } ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

после этого авторизация перестала работать, выдает

> The controller must return a response
> (null given). Did you forget to add a
> return statement somewhere in your
> controller?

И вот не могу понять в чем проблема... Подскажите, 2 дня уже мучаюсь :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Было бы неплохо взглянуть на установку контроллера, ибо прямо говорится, что котроллер не возвращает Response, а должен бы. Что у тебя закодено для роута "/about" (форма и прочее)?

---

Вот рабочий конфиг:

```
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'main' => array(
        'pattern' => '^.*$',
        'anonymous' => true,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/login_check',
        ),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout'),
        'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
            return new UserProvider($app['db']);
        }),
    )
),
'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/private', 'ROLE_USER'),
    array('^.*$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
)
```

1. Любой пользователь может ходить по сайту, но заходя на "/private" и не имея гранта ROLE_USER, он будет перенаправлен на '/login'
2. Роут '/login' -- здесь нужно позаботиться о форме
3. Роут /login_check -- обработка происходит сама по себе, после успешной утентификации будет редирект на homepage или на "/private" в зависимости от того как юзер попал на "/login"
4. Провайдера для юзеров выбери сам

Comment: относительно примера по ссылке изменились только security.firewall

и судя по логике response нет от login_check, но почему я не очень понимаю.

Можно вопрос подругому поставить:
Как сделать все страницы открытыми для анонима, а некоторые сделать доступными только для авторизовавшегося пользователя.

Comment: Ага, спасибо за пример, попробую. А есть вообще именно мануалы или туториалы  с примерами как что делать? В документации только общие принципы.

Comment: Я по правде говоря не нашел плотного набора примеров исключительно для Silex. Я в последние недели плотно занялся Silex'ом, до этого на симфонии сидел. При увеличении практики все больше плюшек симфонии становится ясно как использовать в Silex. В основном разрабы также методом проб и ошибок адаптируют симфоневские конфиги и компоненты к работе в Silex.

Answer (score 1):

Для Silex есть готовый модуль для авторизации и управления пользователями https://github.com/jasongrimes/silex-simpleuser

Comment: вопрос бы про правильнось написания security.firewall, авторизация с точки зрения логина-пароля вопросов не вызвала :)