# Авторизация в Silex

Tags: авторизация, silex

Использую для работы микрофреймворк Silex. не могу настроить авторизацию. все делаю по мануалу. но не получается сделать. 
вот примеры кода

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    /*
    // Ensure that the login page is accessible to all
    'login' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/user/login$',
    ),*/
    'z_backend' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/z/backend',
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/z/login',
            'check_path' => '/z/login_check',
            'username_parameter'=> '_username',
            'password_parameter' => '_password'
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => '/z/logout'
        ),
        'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
            // Specific class App\User\UserProvider is described below
            return new admin\Provider\UserProvider($app['dbs']['z']);
        })
    )
);
```

UserProvider

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(Connection $conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {

        $stmt = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', array(strtolower($username)));
        if (!$user = $stmt->fetch()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
        }

        return new User($user['username'], $user['password'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User';
    }
}
```

Такое ощущение, что UserProvider не грузится. Но если пользователя в фаерволе задать явно, то все равно не работает.

Люди, хэлп. Уже два дня мучаюсь (

Comment: не помогло?: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/249644/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-silex

Comment: сообщите людям что пишет?, что в логах?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу разобраться с авторизацией в silex](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/249644/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-silex)

Answer (score 1):

Алилуйя.... Я разобрался! check_path должен быть в защищенной зоне. А у меня был снаружи. The check_path path must always be defined inside the secured area.